# creat treemap for binary-tree in racket

Tags: binary-tree, racket, treemap

I need help in racket pl

Using this BINTREE definition, write a (higher-order) function called treemap
that takes in a numeric function f and a binary tree, and returns a
tree with the same shape but using f(n) for values in its leaves. For
example, here is a test case:

> (test (tree-map add1 (Node (Leaf 1) (Node (Leaf 2)
>   (Leaf 3))))
>
> => (Node (Leaf 2) (Node (Leaf 3) (Leaf 4))))

What I did is:

> [Node BINTREE BINTREE]
>
> [Leaf Number])

>
>

> (define(treemap f tree)
>
> [(Leaf Number) f(Number)]
>
> [(Node tree BTREE) treemap(Node)]))

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
[(Leaf Number) f(Number)]
```

with

```
[(Leaf Number) (Leaf f(number))]
```

and the Node will return a node and active the functions on its arguments.